# Internal working of virtual and override in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internal Workings of C# Virtual and Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751849/internal-workings-of-c-virtual-and-override)

I want to know how the virtual and override is working in c#. For example

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Display()
    {}
}


class Derived: Base
{
    public override void Display()
    {}
}

Main()
{
    Base obj = new Derived();

    obj.Display();
}
```

It will call derived class "Display" method.

How the object knows it should call Derived.Display(), not Base.Display()?

Comment: `Main` shouldn't be able to call `Display`.

Comment: @Daniel: simple Edit, the intentions were clear.

Comment: You do get a compiler warning that you should use the "new" keyword: warning CS0114: Derived.Display() hides inherited member Base.Display(). To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

when encountered with a virtual method the IL emitted will be `callvirt` which checks if the method has been overriden in any of its derived classes at run time.That is the reason why Display in derived class will get called.

You can check the IL emitted to see.

Comment: I think C# always emits CallVirt. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921893/whats-the-meaning-of-this-in-c/6921917#6921917

Comment: @Henk Holterman ...yes. To be on the safer side..

Answer (score 0):

It will execute the closest definition of the method. However, if you call `base.Display` from `Derived.Display`, it will execute the base class's version.

**Note:**
Also, because `Display` is protected, it cannot be called from where you are using it.